# How Send parameter in controller to view in Laravel 8 Mail

Tags: php, laravel, email, controller

i create system in Laravel 8 .in Case it have option admin user register inside system. I need send email to create user with email and passcode.i case i create php mail class as below

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class RegisterMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;


    public function __construct()
    {
        //$this->data = $data; 
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('emails.register')
               ->subject('Register SLeAgro Agricultural Product Distribution System');
    }
}
```

so in user creation controller i access mail class as below

```
     $data1 = [
               'email' => $request->email,
               'password' => $code
            ];
    
            $mail = new registerMail();
    
            Mail::to($request->email)->send($mail)

;
```

my problem is how send $data1 data into to view as user name and password ?

```
@component('mail::message')
# Welcome SleAgro Agricultural Product Management System

you can loging to the system using following credetail .

User name :
<br> 
password : 

@component('mail::button', ['url' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/login'])
Login
@endcomponent

Thanks,<br>
{{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
```

can you give me way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

at RegisterMail

```
    private $data;

    public function __construct($data) // <-
    {
        $this->data = $data; 
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('emails.register',[ 'data' => $this->data])
               ->subject('Register SLeAgro Agricultural Product Distribution System');
    }
```

At controller

```
     $data1 = [
               'email' => $request->email,
               'password' => $code
            ];
    
     $mail = new RegisterMail($data1);
    
     Mail::to($request->email)->send($mail);
```

Last thing the blade, you can use `$data` variable like any variable in blade.

Comment: Undefined variable: data in mail class.

Comment: RegisterMail how identify $data variable

Comment: try to change `private $data;` to `public $data;`

Comment: You pass data from the controller to RegisterMail, this line `new RegisterMail($data1)`

Comment: still show Undefined variable: data.when change public $data;

Comment: $this->data = $data; show as error line

Comment: I don't see any problem with this line.

Comment: did you add `$data` parameter to `__construct`?

Comment: Must look like that `public function __construct($data)`